# local notification with alertbox

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it possible to pops up an alertbox with message in it for local notification just like remote notification? On my galaxy S6, remote notification pops up an alertbox but not local notification. I'm wondering if it's something to do with phone settings, an option that I need to set in my code or just the nature of android local notification.

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html ?

Comment: I know I can create alertbox. But with remote notification, android does that for me. So I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing any settings for local notification